# Matrix calculus - computing the Hessian of a vector-Matrix equation.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, matrix-calculus

Let $\vec{b}=\langle b_1,\dots,b_n\rangle ^T$ be an n-dimensional vector of coefficients. Let $\vec{x}_1,\dots,\vec{x}_n$ be $n$ $p$-dimensional vectors. Let $G(\vec{b})=\log\det\left( \sum_{i=1}^n b_i \vec{x}_i\vec{x}_i^T\right)$.

Let $A=\sum_{i=1}^n b_i \vec{x}_i\vec{x}_i^T$. If one wants to compute the $i$-th component of the gradient, we get

\begin{eqnarray}
\nabla_i G(\vec{b}) &=& \text{Tr}\left(\partial_i A \right) \\
&=& \text{Tr}\left( A^{-1} \vec{x}_i\vec{x}_i^T \right) \\
&=& \text{Tr}\left(\vec{x}_i^T A^{-1} \vec{x}_i  \right) \\
&=& x_i^T A^{-1} x_i
\end{eqnarray}

I am filling in the details so far of [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1401.3424) (page 19, before equation (33)). So far I agree with their calculation. However, I do not understand their calculation of the line (33) and (34) in which they calculate the Hessian.

They claim that 
$$
\nabla^2_{ij} (G(\vec{b})) = -(\vec{x}_i^T A^{-1}\vec{x}_j)^2.  \tag1
$$

I get something different. Using the [Matrix Cookbook](http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~hwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf)  (equation (61)), I see that 
\begin{eqnarray}
\partial_j(\vec{x}_i^T A^{-1} \vec{x}_i) &=& -A^{-1}\vec{x}_i\vec{x}_i^T A^{-1}\cdot\partial_i(A) \tag2\\
&=& -A^{-1}\vec{x}_i\vec{x}_i^T A^{-1} \vec{x}_j\vec{x}_j^T,
\end{eqnarray}
which is a matrix and not a scalar!

I know I must be making a mistake somewhere. I am still not quite comfortable with matrix calculus.

Can someone help me figure out where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The derivation in (2) is wrong. You apply the formula (61) from the Matrix Cookbook, but this formula is for the derivative of the quadratic form with respect to the *whole* matrix. That's why it is a matrix. You need to calculate the derivative of $G_i'$ with respect of the variable $b_j$ only, so you are rather to use the equation (59) in the Cookbook. Here how it goes
$$
G_{ij}''=[G_i']_j'=\frac{\partial x_i^TA^{-1}x_i}{\partial b_j}=
x_i^T\frac{\partial A^{-1}}{\partial b_j}x_i\stackrel{\text{Eq.(59)}}{=}
x_i^T\Bigl(-A^{-1}\underbrace{\frac{\partial A}{\partial b_j}}_{x_jx_j^T}A^{-1}\Bigr)x_i=\\=-x_i^TA^{-1}x_j\cdot x_j^TA^{-1}x_i
$$
which is exactly their expression (1).

---

UPDATE explaining the formula (61) in the Matrix Cookbook.

In one dimensional calculus we have $f\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ and differentiating according to
$$
f(x+h)-f(x)=\underbrace{f'(x)\cdot h}_{\partial_x f}+o(|h|).\tag{*}
$$
When $x$ becomes a vector and $f\colon\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$, the derivative becomes a vector of partial derivatives (gradient) which normally has the same size as the vector $x$ so that on the place for $x_k$ one gets the partial derivative $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_k}$
$$
x=\left[\matrix{x_1\\x_2\\\vdots\\x_n}\right]\qquad\Rightarrow\qquad\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=
\left[\matrix{\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}\\\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2}\\\vdots\\\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_n}}\right].
$$
The differential in (*) is then no longer a multiplication, it becomes the *scalar product*, i.e. the sum of pointwise multiplications between the gradient and the variable $h$
$$
f(x+h)-f(h)=\langle\frac{\partial f}{\partial x},h\rangle+o(\|h\|).
$$
When one has a function $f\colon\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}\to \mathbb{R}$, for example, $f(X)=a^TX^{-1}b$ as in (61), it is also convenient to organize the matrix of partial derivatives in the same way that on the position for $x_{ij}$ we get $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{ij}}$, and this matrix is denoted by $\frac{\partial f}{\partial X}$, however, the differential is not $\partial f=\frac{\partial f}{\partial X}\partial X$ as you wrote in (2), but as in the vector case the *scalar product*, i.e.
$$
\partial f=\langle\frac{\partial f}{\partial x},\partial X\rangle=
\text{tr}\Bigl(\biggl(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\biggr)^T\partial X\Bigr).
$$
So the corrected version of (2) would be 
$$
\text{tr}(-A^{-1}x_ix_i^TA^{-1}x_jx_j^T)=-(x_j^TA^{-1}x_i)^2.
$$

Comment: Thanks @A.G., but I am not quite following how you justify integrating "through" the quadratic form to the inverse. I.e., can you explain how you get the third equality?

I had thought I was applying the chain rule, essentially. This is why I integrated first with respect to the whole matrix $A^-1$.

Comment: @Lepidopterist The third equality is the derivative of the product (Eq. (37) in the Cookbook). For three matrices one gets $(\partial x_i^T)A^{-1}x_i+x_i^T(\partial A^{-1})x_i+x_i^TA^{-1}(\partial x_i)$, but the first and the last terms are zeros since $x_i$ does not depend on $b_j$. Chain rule for matrices should respect the order of multiplication, since the factors are not commutative, derivation is applied to matrices *at their positions*, you cannot just plug in $\partial_j A$ at the end.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I wonder if you might briefly explain where (61) comes from then. As I understand your reasoning, the derivative should look like $a^tA^{-2}b$, which of course it is not...

Comment: @Lepidopterist Ok, I think I understand now your question. It comes from the interpreting the derivative $\partial f/\partial X$ for a matrix variable $X$. I've added the explanation to the answer, hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can recast this problem into a purely matrix form.

Let $X\in {\mathbb R}^{p\times n}$ denote the matrix whose columns are the {$x_k$} vectors, and let the matrix $\,\,B={\rm Diag}(b)$.

Then the function can be written
$$\eqalign{
 A &= X\,B\,X^T \cr
 G &= \log \det (A) = {\rm tr}\,\log(A) \cr
}$$
Notice that $A$ and $B$ are symmetric.

Find the differential of the function, and successively substitute variables until we arive at an expression involving $db$
$$\eqalign{
 dG &= A^{-T}:dA \cr
    &= A^{-1}:X\,dB\,X^T \cr
    &= X^TA^{-1}X:dB \cr
    &= X^TA^{-1}X:{\rm Diag}(db) \cr
    &= {\rm diag}(X^TA^{-1}X):db \cr
}$$
Since $dG = \frac{\partial G}{\partial b}\!:\!db,\,$ the gradient is
$$\eqalign{
 G^\prime = \frac{\partial G}{\partial b} &= {\rm diag}(X^TA^{-1}X) \cr\cr
}$$

To find the Hessian, start by taking the differential of the gradient
$$\eqalign{
 dG^\prime &= {\rm diag}(X^T\,dA^{-1}\,X) \cr
   &= -{\rm diag}(X^TA^{-1}\,dA\,A^{-1}X) \cr
   &= -{\rm diag}(X^TA^{-1}X\,dB\,X^TA^{-1}X) \cr
   &= -{\rm diag}(C\,dB\,C) \cr
   &= -{\rm diag}(C\,{\rm Diag}(db)\,C) \cr
}$$
where I have collected some common matrix factors into $C=(X^TA^{-1}X),\,$ which is also a symmetric matrix.

Here is a handy formula from Thomas Minka which converts the diag-diag operation into a Hadamard (aka element-wise) product:
$$
{\rm diag}(A\,{\rm Diag}(x)\,B) = (B^T\circ A)\,x 
$$
Applying Minka's formula yields
$$\eqalign{
 dG^\prime &= -(C\circ C)\,db \cr
}$$
from which the Hessian is seen to be
$$\eqalign{
 G^{\prime\prime} &= -(C\circ C) \cr
   &= -(X^TA^{-1}X)\circ(X^TA^{-1}X) \cr
}$$